# How to create a multiqueue tap device in Linux?

Tags: qemu, kvm, tap

I've tried with the following command to create a tap device `tap0` for my virtual machine `vm1`:

```
$ tunctl -t tap0 -u root
$ brctl addif br0 tap0
$ ifconfig tap0 up
```

When check its channels I got the following error:

```
$ ethtool -l tap0
Cannot get device channel parameters
: Operation not supported
```

I thought maybe the method I create `tap0` is incorrect but I don't know the correct way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the question, I still don't know how to achieve it. But I found another way to create multiqueue tap devices for VM with `qemu-kvm`. Here is my script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

qemu-kvm -name vm1 -smp cpus=8 -m 8192 \
        -drive file=/opt/kvm/vm1.qcow2,if=virtio \
        -netdev tap,id=dev0,script=no,downscript=no,ifname=tap0,vhost=on,queues=8 \
        -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=dev0,mac=52:54:00:56:78:90,mq=on,vectors=18 \
        -daemonize

if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        sleep 5
        brctl addif br1 tap0
        ifconfig tap0 up
fi
```

The script creates a tap device `tap0` with 8 queues, adds `tap0` to bridge `br0`, and sets `tap0` up.

You can use `ethtool -l [ifname]` in your VM, here is my output:

```
$ ethtool -l eth0
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             0
TX:             0
Other:          0
Combined:       8
Current hardware settings:
RX:             0
TX:             0
Other:          0
Combined:       8         # current has 8 queues enabled
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to setup multiqueue tun0 device.

```bash
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap group netdev multi_queue
```

Then I ran the QEMU VM with the following settings for networking.

```bash
NETWORK=" -netdev tap,ifname=${TAP:-tap0},id=n1,script=no,downscript=no,queues=4 -device virtio-net-pci,mac=AA:BB:CC:DD:CA:B1,netdev=n1,mq=on,vectors=18"
```

Important options are `virtio-net-pci` and `mq=on,vectors=18`.
Information about the vectors parameter https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Multiqueue

Also, in order to prevent QEMU from trying to manage tap0, I disable scripts `script=no,downscript=no`

My results

```
root@ubuntu:/shared# ethtool -l ens5
Channel parameters for ens5:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       4
Current hardware settings:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       2
```

Distribution of interrupts between two cores (I run vm with two cores)

```
root@ubuntu:/shared# cat /proc/interrupts |grep virtio.-input
 28:   20079840          0   PCI-MSI 81921-edge      virtio1-input.0
 30:          1   20235243   PCI-MSI 81923-edge      virtio1-input.1
 32:          0          0   PCI-MSI 81925-edge      virtio1-input.2
 34:          0          0   PCI-MSI 81927-edge      virtio1-input.3
```